# How far can a character move in combat?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

In Shadowrun Returns, what determines how far a character can move for each AP in combat?

I noticed my tanky Troll can't move as far as some of the human allies I met early in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickness affects your chance to hit with Ranged Attacks and to Dodge. I haven't played a Troll, but I think base move speed for every characters is the same. There are a few ways you can increase move speed for your character:

- Equip clothes that give + to move speed (Stealth Suit, Ninja Outfit,etc give +1; Street Brawler gives +2)
- There is at least one Cyber Implant that gives + to move speed (Wired Reflex)
- Racoon Totem spell gives +2 to movement for all allies within range.
- If your character focuses on Chi Casting, the Stride spell gives +4 to move

Comment: If playing Dragonfall, don't forget the drugs, chummer! Like Jazz and Flash and, uh.. what's that other one, starts with a D I think.. buy as much as you can in the first bar, it's hard to come by, but oh so awesome.

Comment: Aaah Shadowrun, the only place were taking drugs makes you more effective.

Answer (score 1):

The base movement is 6 squares per Action Point.  This is true for all races and stats (e.g. Quickness 9 doesn't change it).  The only things that affect it are things like what Jeremy shared that specifically mention bonus to Movement (Blur spell, Hydraulic Jacks, some drugs, etc.).